# a black image's color can not be changed in Unity

Tags: image, colors, unity-game-engine

the color of a black image , or the black part of a image, can not be changed.
[image: example]

I set the image's color to red, but the image is still black.

Is that a desired feature?

What i want is , the image is changed to red.

the Unity version is 5.0.1f.
I am using the new UI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To understand the source of the problem, you have to understand how "changing colors" work. It's nothing but a simple multiplication. In RGB terms, "black" is a vector of (0, 0, 0) — and it's pretty obvious, that whatever you multiply the 0 by, it stays black.

If you want the template image to be able to change to any color, use white.

To modify colours in a more complex way, you have to understand how the `Color` property of a `Image` component works. UI system hides a lot of complexity underneath (and it's good). Basically, `Color` modifies the vertex colours of a mesh. Since you don't usually specify a material, a default sprite material is used, and it uses a default sprite shader. And inside this shader, when it paints the pixels on the screen, it multiplies the vertex colours by the texture colour sampled at this pixel, and that's how it produces the end result. If you want the colours to be combined in a different way, you'll have to write a custom shader — which is really not as hard, but you probably don't need it for what you're trying to do in the scope of this question.

Comment: great reply. Is there a way to change black into other color?

Comment: Added it to an answer, since it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Great!  you gave me more. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Black stays black.

White, however, will change with whatever Color you choose, so if you use an image editor and make your image be white instead of black, the image can then be whatever color you choose within Unity.

Comment: got it.  Editing images costs much time.  How  to change color of any image by scripting whether black or not?

Comment: Editing the image in an editor will be quicker than writing a shader for it. (For this specific example)

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your image has an alpha channel. You can do this with GIMP or Photoshop.  If it does, then check your shader/material to ensure that it's set to transparent/diffuse (and not just diffuse).  Diffuse only doesn't apply the alpha property to the material.

Also, it doesn't look like you assigned a material...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have used `yourImage.canvasRenderer.SetColor`.

For example:

```
damageAnim.canvasRenderer.SetColor (new Color (255, 255, 255, 255));
```